indicator function of a stopping time
Let $T$ be a stopping time (in continuous time), this means $\{\omega \in \Omega: T(\omega)\leq t\}\in\mathcal F_t$ and $a,b \in\mathbb R_+, n\in\mathbb N$. Is it true that $S:=a\cdot \mathbb 1_{T\leq n}+b\cdot \mathbb 1_{T>n}$ is also a stopping time? Intuitively I would say yes, but how can I prove it?

S is in general not a stopping time if you choose $a\neq b$ with $b<n$ or $a < n$.
Intuitively, if S is a stopping time, it is able to rationally tell you to stop at either $a$ or $b$, as soon as you know that $T\leq n$ or $T> n$ respectively. But to know whether $T\leq n$ or $T> n$, you sometimes have to check for every $t$ up to $t=n$.
If we had $a = \frac n2$ and $b = n+1$ for example, then at $t = \frac{2n}{3}$, we have $a < t < n < b$, and it can be still undetermined at time $t$ whether $T$ is above or below $n$. However, since $S$ can only take two values, $$\{\omega \in \Omega: S(\omega) \leq t\} = \{\omega \in \Omega: S(\omega) = a\} = \{\omega \in \Omega: T(\omega) \leq n\}.$$
Thus $S$ is in general not a stopping time.

What if $X$ is a process defined on $[0,1]$ and $a=\frac{n-1}{n}$ and $b=1$?

You mean $T$ is a stopping time for process $X$ and filtration $(\mathcal F^X,(\mathcal F_t^X)_{t\in [0,1]})$? If so then I still have $a < b$ with $a < n$ so taking $t\in (a,\min(b,n))$ (for example $t = \frac{2n-1}{2n}$) leads to the same argument as in my original response.
